# C# IsChecked does not check radiobutton

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

On a different controller, i have 3 radiobuttons.
I want these to be used for a filter.

Right now, i get these values via this:

```
public static void test(Filter filter)
{
    if (filter.Equals(Filter.x))
    {
        SiteStatusControl test = new SiteStatusControl();   //This is working
        test.e.IsChecked = true;                            //This does not make my radiobutton selected.
    }
    else if (filter.Equals(Filter.y))
    {
        SiteStatusControl test = new SiteStatusControl();   //This is working
        test.f.IsChecked = true;                            //This does not make my radiobutton selected.
    }
    else if (filter.Equals(Filter.z))
    {
        SiteStatusControl test = new SiteStatusControl();  //This is working
        test.g.IsChecked = true;                           //This does not make my radiobutton selected.
    }
}
```

When i click a radio button in the controller, it goes there. This is working.

However, i want to make a different radio button active via this.
That's what you see in the code : `test.e.IsChecked = true;`

However, i see the code walking through all this when i debug it, but it does not make the radio button active/selected...

The design of the radio button that i want to make active:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <RadioButton x:Name="e" Content="All" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="f" Content="Atlas" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="g" Content="Phoenix" />
</StackPanel>
```

Sorry if it's hard to understand the question, but it's hard to explain for me.

Basically i want to make a radio button active, by clicking a radio button in a different controller.
I can get the selected value of this different controller, but it does not make the other radio button active.

Comment: I think that you need call RaisePropertyChanged after change check. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and call RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(property))

Comment: @Szymson I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged like this: **public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;**  And added this: ** INotifyPropertyChanged** in my public class. This is working and not giving me errors. However, can you give me a example based of my code, with the  **RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(property))** ? I'm still new to C# and don't understand everything.